# How to provide an outcome if at least one element is present?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame
'

```
file<-c('510-1','510-1','510-2','510-2','510-4')
sev<-c('F','M','M','M','F')
df<-data.frame(file,sev)
```

I want to create another variable called `category`. If at least one of the `file` have a `sev` of `F` I want the `category` to be named `F`, so that the that the category column would like the following

```
   file sev category
1 510-1   F F
2 510-1   M F
3 510-2   M M
4 510-2   M M
5 510-4   F F
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping, you can use the `any` function in an `if` statement to make the new column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(file) %>% 
  mutate(category = if(any(sev == 'F')) 'F' else 'M')

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups:   file [3]
#   file  sev   category
#   <fct> <fct> <chr>   
# 1 510-1 F     F       
# 2 510-1 M     F       
# 3 510-2 M     M       
# 4 510-2 M     M       
# 5 510-4 F     F
```

Or with data.table (same output)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, category := if(any(sev == 'F')) 'F' else 'M', by = file]
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(file) %>%
    mutate(category = c("M", "F")[sum(sev == "F") + 1])
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   file [3]
#  file  sev   category
#  <fct> <fct> <chr>   
#1 510-1 F     F       
#2 510-1 M     F       
#3 510-2 M     M       
#4 510-2 M     M       
#5 510-4 F     F
```

---

Or using `match`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(file) %>%
   mutate(category = c("F", "M")[match("F", sev, nomatch = 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

`ave` seems to be a simple base R to do what the question asks for. If at least ( `any`) one `sev == 'F'` then the index to subset the potential results vector `c('M', 'F')` is equal to `2`.

```
df$category <- ave(df$sev, df$file, FUN = function(x) c('M', 'F')[1+any(x == 'F')])
df
#   file sev category
#1 510-1   F        F
#2 510-1   M        F
#3 510-2   M        M
#4 510-2   M        M
#5 510-4   F        F
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with `file` and `sev` not being factors, this works and is incredibly quick.

```r
file<-c('510-1','510-1','510-2','510-2','510-4')
sev<-c('F','M','M','M','F')
df<-data.frame(file, sev, stringsAsFactors = F)
lookup = sapply(unique(df$file), FUN = function(f) ifelse(any(df[file == f, 'sev'] == 'F'), 'F', 'M'))
df$category = lookup[df$file]
df
#>    file sev category
#> 1 510-1   F        F
#> 2 510-1   M        F
#> 3 510-2   M        M
#> 4 510-2   M        M
#> 5 510-4   F        F
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>